# how to i add image compress to this php code

Tags: php

my upload are working fine, I want to add image compress to it and I am not sure what the best to do with this code is I have read some stuff online but it just confuses me thanks for the help.

```
// Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = include 'statusMsg/uploaded-successfully.php';
            }else{
                $statusMsg = include 'statusMsg/upload-failed.php';
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg
```

;

Comment: Thanks I have been look into it but sure where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `move_uploaded_file()`, call a function called, say, `compressFile()`:

```
compressFile($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath, $quality) //Quality can be anything you want between 0-100
```

where `compressImage()` can be something like (assuming you want to, for example, compress JPEG, GIFs, etc.)

```
    function compressFile($source, $destination, $quality){
        $info = getimagesize($source);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

        elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

        if(imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality)){
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Let's assume you save that the above function `compressFile()` in a php file where you store all your externally called functions in a file called `functions.php`
Then calling this function in your code (note I included `functions.php`) and assuming you compress the image file to 50%:

```
// Include the database configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';
include 'functions.php';
$statusMsg = '';

// File upload path
$targetDir = "uploads/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
    // Allow certain file formats
    $allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg');
    if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
        // Upload file to server
        if(compressFile($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath, 50)){
            // Insert image file name into database
            $insert = $db->query("INSERT into images (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
            if($insert){
                $statusMsg = include 'statusMsg/uploaded-successfully.php';
            }else{
                $statusMsg = include 'statusMsg/upload-failed.php';
            } 
        }else{
            $statusMsg = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, files are allowed to upload.';
    }
}else{
    $statusMsg = 'Please select a file to upload.';
}

// Display status message
echo $statusMsg
```

Comment: thanks for help I have fix the incomplete code I am not sure I am with you on that example

Comment: @SantoLewis I have edited the answer to include the function ```compressFile``` in your code. Note that I have added return values (```true``` or ```false```) to the ```compressFile``` function